# How to write custom query condition for this search in search api solr

Tags: search, drupal, solr, drupal-7, drupal-modules

[image]

How to passes the search selected choice operator condition in SearchApiQuery() drupal 7

```
$index = search_api_index_load('advance_search_index');
$query = new SearchApiQuery($index);
$query->condition($field_key, $field_value);
$filter = $query->createFilter($parameter['op1']);
$query->filter($filter);
```

// how to add all 3 fields createFilter() condition with parameter basis

Please help me?.